# Perform groupby based on Event Type in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

i have a application which will be tracking all the user activities with screen shots. so i am facing an issue while reporting i want to know that how much time does user has spent on the key press event on particular field.
Here is the Sample Data.

```
 public class UserActivityData
    {
        [DisplayName("Process Name")]
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Window Title")]
        public string WindowTitle { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Event Type")]
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Event Time")]
        public string EventTime { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Total Time Spent In Secs")]
        public string TotalTimeSpent { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Capture Data")]
        public string CaptureData { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationPath { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Element Name")]
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Automation ID")]
        public string AutomationID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Control Type")]
        public string ControlType { get; set; }
        public long LongEventTime { get; set; }
    }


 public enum EventType
  {
    RightClick,
    LeftClick,
    MiddleButton,
    MouseMove,
    DoubleClick,
    KeyPress,
    Copy,
    Paste,
    Focus,
    Open,
    Close,
    FiddlerRequest
 }
```

This is the class that hold the dataSet.

```
[{"ProcessName":"explorer","WindowTitle":"explorer","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:24","X":255,"Y":354,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639643087155},
{"ProcessName":"explorer","WindowTitle":"explorer","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:25","X":253,"Y":268,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639650818276},
{"ProcessName":"explorer","WindowTitle":"explorer","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:25","X":266,"Y":176,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639659717952},
{"ProcessName":"explorer","WindowTitle":"explorer","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:27","X":212,"Y":342,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639670828333},
{"ProcessName":"explorer","WindowTitle":"explorer","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:28","X":129,"Y":542,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639680374536},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:30","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639705742531},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:31","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"r","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639714952510},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:31","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"a","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"r","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639716392533},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:31","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"v","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ra","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639718522707},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"i","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"rav","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639720202589},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"k","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravi","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639722662623},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"a","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravik","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639724112642},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"n","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravika","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639725722813},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"t","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravikan","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639727382686},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:32","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"h","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravikant","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639728952705},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":5,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:34","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"\u0001","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"ravikanth","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639741393315},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":6,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:35","X":589,"Y":301,"CaptureData":"ravikanth","ApplicationPath":"","ElementName":"ravikanth","AutomationID":"1051654","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639751728266},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:37","X":669,"Y":346,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"7930456","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639771735142},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":7,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:38","X":666,"Y":349,"CaptureData":"ravikanth","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"7930456","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639780934311},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:39","X":762,"Y":356,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"20186264","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639792061233},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"Login","EventType":7,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:40","X":762,"Y":356,"CaptureData":"ravikanth","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"","AutomationID":"20186264","ControlType":"edit","LongEventTime":636368639805472017},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:47","X":673,"Y":239,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"Session","AutomationID":"4262798","ControlType":"pane","LongEventTime":636368639876601809},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:48","X":671,"Y":255,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"Drop Down Button","AutomationID":"DropDown","ControlType":"button","LongEventTime":636368639880488395},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:49","X":643,"Y":303,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"WebDAV","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639891350690},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:50","X":806,"Y":259,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"No encryption","AutomationID":"5374814","ControlType":"combo box","LongEventTime":636368639903461809},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:51","X":791,"Y":277,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"TLS/SSL Implicit encryption","AutomationID":"","ControlType":"list item","LongEventTime":636368639912755112},
{"ProcessName":"WinSCP","WindowTitle":"WinSCP","EventType":1,"EventTime":"28-Jul-2017 06:39:52","X":757,"Y":558,"CaptureData":"","ApplicationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe","ElementName":"Close","AutomationID":"1509814","ControlType":"button","LongEventTime":636368639929011583}]
```

I need a help to write a linq query to do the groupby based on the EventType Keypress event and get the total time spent.

[image]

Comment: Hey @ravi can you provide the class that holds your dataset please?

Comment: Is `LongEventTime` the time spent in milliseconds or ticks?

Comment: LongEventTime is the Ticks..

Comment: On which namespace can we find the `EventType` class?

Comment: EventType is my internal Enum which may be LeftClick,RightClick,Keypress, copy Paste etc,.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 small changes to your class:

1. I changed EventType to string, since I did not want to implement your Enumeration.
2. I've changed "EventTime" to the type `DateTime`. This way I do not have to try to parse strings to dates in the query.

With this I used that query:

```
var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<UserActivityData>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\users\foo\desktop\demo.json")); //saved your data locally
data.Where(x => x.EventType == "5") // 5 is KeyPress
    .GroupBy(d => d.ProcessName) //Grouping by ProcessName
    .Select (d => new {
        ProcessName = d.FirstOrDefault().ProcessName,
        //get Max; substract min; get rough duration in seconds
        Duration = d.Max (x => x.EventTime) - d.Min (x => x.EventTime), 
        //sum up all ticks to get duration in ticks
        DurationTicks = d.Sum (x => x.LongEventTime)
    })
    //LinqPad native; do not use in Visual Studio or VS Code
    .Dump();
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: No, unless you tell me, what doesn't work. I cannot see into your head or your computers screen.